# Matching on search attributes selected by customer on front end

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method in a class that allows me to return results based on a certain set of Customer specified criteria. The method matches what the Customer specifies on the front end with each item in a collection that comes from the database. In cases where the customer does not specify any of the attributes, the ID of the attibute is passed into the method being equal to 0 (The database has an identity on all tables that is seeded at 1 and is incremental). In this case that attribute should be ignored, for example if the Customer does not specify the Location then customerSearchCriteria.LocationID = 0 coming into the method. The matching would then match on the other attributes and return all Locations matching the other attibutes, example below:

```
public IEnumerable<Pet> FindPetsMatchingCustomerCriteria(CustomerPetSearchCriteria customerSearchCriteria)
{   
    if(customerSearchCriteria.LocationID == 0)
    {         
         return repository.GetAllPetsLinkedCriteria()
                     .Where(x => x.TypeID == customerSearchCriteria.TypeID &&
                                 x.FeedingMethodID == customerSearchCriteria.FeedingMethodID &&
                                 x.FlyAblityID == customerSearchCriteria.FlyAblityID )
                     .Select(y => y.Pet);
    }
}
```

**The code for when all criteria is specified is shown below:**

```
private PetsRepository repository = new PetsRepository();

public IEnumerable<Pet> FindPetsMatchingCustomerCriteria(CustomerPetSearchCriteria customerSearchCriteria)
{            
    return repository.GetAllPetsLinkedCriteria()
                     .Where(x => x.TypeID == customerSearchCriteria.TypeID &&
                                 x.FeedingMethodID == customerSearchCriteria.FeedingMethodID &&
                                 x.FlyAblityID == customerSearchCriteria.FlyAblityID &&
                                 x.LocationID == customerSearchCriteria.LocationID )
                     .Select(y => y.Pet);
}
```

I want to avoid having a whole set of **if and else statements** to cater for each time the Customer does not explicitly select an attribute of the results they are looking for. What is the most succint and efficient way in which I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criteria that are not selected are always zero, right? So how about taking rows where the field equals the criteria OR the criteria equals zero.

This should work

```
private PetsRepository repository = new PetsRepository();

public IEnumerable<Pet> FindPetsMatchingCustomerCriteria(CustomerPetSearchCriteria customerSearchCriteria)
{
    return repository.GetAllPetsLinkedCriteria()
                     .Where(x => (customerSearchCriteria.TypeID == 0 || x.TypeID == customerSearchCriteria.TypeID)&&
                                 (customerSearchCriteria.FeedingMethodID == 0 || x.FeedingMethodID == customerSearchCriteria.FeedingMethodID) &&
                                 (customerSearchCriteria.FlyAblityID == 0 || x.FlyAblityID == customerSearchCriteria.FlyAblityID) &&
                                 (customerSearchCriteria.LocationID == 0 || x.LocationID == customerSearchCriteria.LocationID))
                     .Select(y => y.Pet);
}
```

Alternatively, if this is something you find yourself doing alot of, you could write an alternate `Where` extension method that either applies the criteria or passes through if zero, and chain the calls instead of having one condition with the criteria anded. Then you'd do the comparision for the criteria == 0 just once per query, not for every unmatched row. I'm not sure that it's worth the - *possible* - marginal performance increase, you'd be better off applying the filters in the database if you want a performance gain.
Here it is anyway, for the purposes of edification . . .

```
static class Extns
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereZeroOr<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, int> idAccessor, int id)
    {
        if (id == 0)
            return items;
        else
            return items.Where(x => idAccessor(x) == id);
    }
}

private PetsRepository repository = new PetsRepository();

public IEnumerable<Pet> FindPetsMatchingCustomerCriteria(CustomerPetSearchCriteria customerSearchCriteria)
{
    return repository.GetAllPetsLinkedCriteria()
        .WhereZeroOr(x => x.TypeID, customerSearchCriteria.TypeID)
        .WhereZeroOr(x => x.FeedingMethodID, customerSearchCriteria.FeedingMethodID)
        .WhereZeroOr(x => x.FlyAblityID, customerSearchCriteria.FlyAblityID)
        .WhereZeroOr(x => x.LocationID, customerSearchCriteria.LocationID);
}
```

Comment: Your first method is wrong I believe. I wrote something close to your second method, but I guess mine would be faster, just saying..

Comment: @nawfal: Could you elucidate the theory behind your belief as to why my first method is incorrect? Also, your answer below is functionally identical to my first method (except you check for zero first). Your method (and my first) perform this check for every item in the sequence. My second method will only perform the zero check once for each criteria before the sequence is iterated over.

Comment: Sorry you're right. At first it appeared wrong to me. In that case its the best method and the most readable!! About the second argument, you are performing 4 `Where` on a single clause while I'm performing one `Where` on 4 clauses, it appears the latter is more efficient. Just my thinking though I'm aware of deferred execution..

Comment: @nawfal: I agree, it **might** very well be slower, however the JIT optimizer can **potentially** do some magic with the loop in each call to `WhereZeroOr`. Now, I highlighted _might_ & _potentially_ in the previous statement for good reason, because without timing the different implementations you really can't say which will be faster, or why. I don't have time to benchmark these at the moment, and can't see myself doing it anytime soon. You want to give it a go mate?

Comment: Yes I did, yours was fractionally slower. Your first method is the fastest, mine is in btw.. :)

Comment: @nawfal: Was it for a Release build? Can you give me your timings, and number of iterations etc? Thanks :)

Comment: In debug, your first method and mine was close but the former ran marginally faster. There was bigger difference with your second method. In release, your first method and mine was close again, but this time very narrowly I felt mine ran faster while your second method was slowest again with the same margin. But all three ran faster in release build.

Comment: In release build, mine: 112 ms, your first : 117ms, your second: 150ms, for 100000 iterations for 5 objectis in list.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using a stored procedure and you're getting all records first and then doing your filtration. I suggest you filter at the stored procedure level, letting the database do the heavy lifting and any micro filtration that you need to do afterwords will be easier. In your sproc, have your params default to NULL and make your properties nullable for the criteria object so you can just pass in values and the sproc will(should) be corrected to work with these null values, i.e.

```
 private PetsRepository repository = new PetsRepository();

    public IEnumerable<Pet> FindPetsMatchingCustomerCriteria(CustomerPetSearchCriteria customerSearchCriteria)
    {
        return repository.GetAllPetsLinkedCriteria(customerSearchCriteria.TypeID,customerSearchCriteria.FeedingMethodID,customerSearchCriteria.FlyAblityID,customerSearchCriteria.LocationID).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing an elegant solution. May be this:

```
IEnumerable<Pet> FindPetsMatchingCustomerCriteria(CustomerPetSearchCriteria customerSearchCriteria)
{
    return repository.GetAllPetsLinkedCriteria()
                     .Where(x => 
                      Check(x.TypeID, customerSearchCriteria.TypeID) &&
                      Check(x.FeedingMethodID, customerSearchCriteria.FeedingMethodID) &&
                      Check(x.FlyAblityID, customerSearchCriteria.FlyAblityID) &&
                      Check(x.LocationID, customerSearchCriteria.LocationID))
                     .Select(x => x.Pet);
}

static bool Check(int petProperty, int searchCriteriaProperty)
{
    return searchCriteriaProperty == 0 || petProperty == searchCriteriaProperty;
}
```